# Solspace Facebook Login - Dynamic Return with {segment}

Tags: solspace, facebook

Might be an odd scenario, but i'm looking to use Solspace's facebook Login with a dynamic return by using segments in the url.

Currenttly fbc:login throws an error when I use any {segment} tags in the parameters.

Here's how they say to use the module:
{exp:fbc:login
    permissions="email|publish_stream|read_stream"
    return_when_logged_in="site/home"
    return_when_logged_out="site/home"
    return_to_register="site/register"
    return_on_failure="site/fail"
}
{/exp:fbc:login}

Here's what i'd like to do

{exp:fbc:login
    permissions="email|publish_stream|read_stream"
    return_when_logged_in="{segment_2}/{segment_2}"
    return_when_logged_out="s{segment_2}/{segment_2}"
    return_to_register="site/register"
    return_on_failure="site/fail"
}
{/exp:fbc:login}

Comment: Alright. I got one answer. Its to have return_when_logged_in="/'{segment_2}'" and so on.. Perhaps a dirty solve, but it works.

Comment: I would turn on **Template Debugging** and see how the values in these parameters are parsing in the {exp:fbc:login} tag.

Comment: This is what i'm getting: return_when_logged_in="/'pricing'/''/''/'" return_for_passive_register="/'pricing'/''/''/'"  It's not the best because we have all of the slashes and ' from the segments. It won't allow conditionals. Is this a major issue?

Comment: Is this output after using your "hack", or when using `return_when_logged_in="{segment_2}/{segment_2}"`?

Comment: sorry - should have clarified.  Here's the actual tag: {exp:fbc:login
         permissions="email"
         return_when_logged_in="/'{segment_2}'/'{segment_3}'/'{segment_4}'"


Then, depending what my segments are, the out put would be: return_when_logged_in="/'pricing'/''/''/'"  

My goal is to redirect users back to their task-flow. But they need to login/register before doing so.

Comment: What I wanted to know is what is displayed in the Template Debugger when using `return_when_logged_in="{segment_2}/{segment_3}/{segment_4}"`, i.e. your initial code/not what your current solution displays. Also please provide the actual error that you were seeing when using your initial code.

Comment: Ah my bad. A moment like this deserves this:http://bit.ly/Nxqarp  Alright, Here's my original code that was causing an error: return_when_logged_in="{if segment_2}/'{segment_2}'{if:elseif segment_3}'{segment_2}'/'{segment_3}'/{if:elseif segment_4}'{segment_2}'/'{segment_3}/'{segment_4}'{if:else}/{/if}". It's essentially what I have now, except I tried cleaning it up so the output wasn't //pricing/. The OUTPUT: was "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters." it doesn't give me the template debugger - Just a blank page with that message

Comment: There's the issue: you're using an **advanced conditional** within an `{exp:...}` tag's parameter. This gets parsed **after** the `{exp:...}` tag, which likely is giving you the error. I'll expand my answer as an actual EESE answer (funny pic, btw) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this kind of conditional in a parameter won't work well:

```
return_when_logged_in="{if segment_2}/'{segment_2}'{if:elseif segment_3}'{segment_2}'/'{segment_3}'/{if:elseif segment_4}'{segment_2}'/'{segment_3}/'{segment_4}'{if:else}/{/if}"
```

First, you shouldn't need those single quotes, as this could cause more issues than less.

Also with the above, you're using an **advanced conditional** within an `{exp:...}` tag's parameter. This gets parsed **after** the `{exp:...}` tag, which likely is giving you the error. Always use **simple conditionals** when working with parameters. In this case you could simply try:

```
return_when_logged_in="/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/{segment_4}"
```

However, your return URL may have a number of slashes at the end, eg. `http://mysite.com/template_group/template//`.

A better solution is the following, all using **simple conditionals**:

```
return_when_logged_in="{if segment_2}/{segment_2}{/if}{if segment_3}/{segment_3}{/if}{if segment_4}/{segment_4}{/if}"
```

Notice how all conditionals are simple conditionals. These will parse **before** the `{exp:...}` tag.

This is general EE advice, by the way, so can come in handy with 1st- and 3rd-party tags.

Comment: Great - Thanks for looking into that! Sorry it was a bit of pulling teeth for getting my result.